# CSS max-width for an img makes IE use the 'original' div/table width

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have a website where users can send their RICH text description.

I'm using `max-width` property for images inside the `div` (tried table too) that contains this description.

It's working perfectly of FF and Chrome but giving me some trouble (as always) on IE.

The thing is that, on IE, the images are resized (reduced) but the `div` still acts like it has one big image there.

Right on FF and Chrome:

[image: http://www.meuleague.com/legends/images/unrelated/no-bug.jpg]

Problem on IE:

[image: http://www.meuleague.com/legends/images/unrelated/bug-ie.jpg]

So, can you people help me? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle that exhibits the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, I'm sure you're using the 'float' property (which is fine), bus still, for it to work under (the horrible) IE, you need to give every div the 'height' and 'width' properties, even if they get it from someone else, or by default.
Then just organize it properly, and you're done.